# Why it is impossible to change 'Build action' resource's property in WPF solution?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, path, resources

Just like on the screen below. For some raeson, I can't change 'build action' property. I'm trying to change window's background using this code:

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Solution Items/lol2.png"/>
</Window.Background >
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot locate resource 'Solution Items/lol2.png'.
```

[image]

Comment: In order to be "buildable" the file would have to be part of a project, perhaps the Notatnik one.

Comment: @Clemens would you like to post that comment as an answer? I don't like to have unanswered questions (which actually do have an answer) in the WPF tag =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be "buildable" the file would have to be part of a project. A stand-alone solution item won't be built.

From [How to: Add and Remove Solution Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1ee8zw5t.aspx):

> Solution items are internal items. They can be referenced by projects,
>   but are never included in solution or project builds

Comment: I've just dragged and dropped that file to 'Notatnik' and this worked. Thank you! :)